# Loading several different queries in Leaflet overlays?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, overlay

I am trying to make a map preview with different sensors, and I am not able to use different queries for different overlays. So my code is below:

```
    async function getdata() {
        const response = await fetch('https://iot.hamburg.de/v1.1/Things?$expand=Locations&$resultFormat=GeoJSON&$top=1500');
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        const {features} = data;
        var map = L.map('map').setView([53.543139, 9.989990], 13);
        var osm = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            });
        osm.addTo(map);

        //create marker
        var all = L.layerGroup();
        var Ladestationen = L.layerGroup();
        var StadtRad = L.layerGroup();
        var Auto = L.layerGroup();
        var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>';
        var mbUrl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw';
        var grayscale = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/light-v9', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr});
        var streets = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/streets-v11', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr});
        var baseLayers = {
        'Grayscale': grayscale,
        'Streets': streets
        };

        var overlays = {
        'All': all,
        'E-Ladestationen': Ladestationen,
        'StadtRad_Fahrrader': StadtRad,
        'AutomatisierteVerkehrsmengenerfassung': Auto
        };

        var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);

        for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
            var l = features[i].geometry.coordinates[0];
            var lo = features[i].geometry.coordinates[1];
            //var l = data.value[i].Locations[0].location.geometry.coordinates[0];
            //var lo = data.value[i].Locations[0].location.geometry.coordinates[0];

            var des = features[i].properties.description;
            var nam = features[i].properties.name;
            var owner = features[i].properties["properties/ownerThing"];
            var link = features[i].properties["Locations/0/@iot.selfLink"];
            //var lo = features[i].geometry.coordinates[1];

            var myIcon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: '6726652_preview.png',
                iconSize: [23, 31],
                iconAnchor: [22, 94],
                popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
                //shadowUrl: '2540201.png',
                //shadowSize: [68, 95],
                //shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
            });

                
            marker = new L.marker([lo,l], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(all);
            //var singleMarker = L.marker([lo, l]).addTo(map);
            var popup = marker.bindPopup('<p>Sensor name: ' + nam + '<br />Description: ' + des + '<br />Owner: ' + owner + '<br />Link to server: ' + link + '</p>')
            marker.addTo(map)
            popup.addTo(map)    

        }
getdata();
```

So, what I am trying is to use a different query for example Overlays - Ladestationen, and to make a preview out of it.

```
const response2 = await fetch('https://iot.hamburg.de/v1.1/Things?$expand=Locations&$filter=Datastreams/properties/serviceName%20eq%20%27HH_STA_E-Ladestationen%27&$resultFormat=GeoJSON&$top=1000');
            const data2 = await response2.json();
            console.log(data2);
            const {features2} = data2;
```

How can I do it?

Comment: @TomazicM to have all sensors on the map, when the layer "All" is checked. And now there is a category with E-Ladestationen, and I can query it with this "https://iot.hamburg.de/v1.1/Things?$expand=Locations&$filter=Datastreams/properties/serviceName%20eq%20%27HH_STA_E-Ladestationen%27&$resultFormat=GeoJSON&$top=1000", but I don't know how to write it into JavaScript

Comment: @TomazicM how can I do this instead? I need the markers to show them on the map, and I did this with for loop. And also how could I add from this second query on the layer 'E-Ladestationen': Ladestationen'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main things should be changed in your approach to loading and displaying vector/marker data from GeoJSON source:

1. Async loading function should be used only for vector GeoJSON data, not for the whole map.
2. Since your vector source is GeoJSON, Leaflet `L.geoJSON` should be used for creating layer/markers and adding popup to the markers. Instead of looping through retrieved features yourselves, layer option `pointToLayer` can be used for that.

So code could then look something like this:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([53.543139, 9.989990], 13);
var osm = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
});
osm.addTo(map);

var mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>';
var mbUrl = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw';
var grayscale = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/light-v9', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr});
var streets = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox/streets-v11', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, attribution: mbAttr});

var baseLayers = {
  'OSM': osm,
  'Grayscale': grayscale,
  'Streets': streets
};

var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers, null, {
  sortLayers: true,
  sortFunction: function (layerA, layerB) {
    var retVal = (layerA.options.order) ? (layerA.options.order - layerB.options.order) : 1;
    return(retVal);
  }
}).addTo(map);

async function getdata(url, overlayDesc, icon, order) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  var vectorLayer = L.geoJSON(data, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
      var des = feature.properties.description;
      var nam = feature.properties.name;
      var owner = feature.properties["properties/ownerThing"];
      var link = feature.properties["Locations/0/@iot.selfLink"];
      var popupContent = '<p><b>Sensor name</b>: ' + nam + 
                         '<br />Description: ' + des + 
                         '<br /><b>Owner</b>: ' + owner +
                         '<br /><b>Link to server</b>: ' + link + '</p>';
      var marker = L.marker(latlng, {icon: icon}).bindPopup(popupContent);
      return(marker);
    },
    order: order
  });
  layerControl.addOverlay(vectorLayer, overlayDesc);
}

var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '6726652_preview.png',
    iconSize: [23, 31],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
});

var myIcon2 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'some_other_preview.png',
    iconSize: [23, 31],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
});
  
allUrl = 'https://iot.hamburg.de/v1.1/Things?$expand=Locations&$resultFormat=GeoJSON&$top=1500';
getdata(allUrl, 'All', myIcon, 1);

ladestationenUrl = 'https://iot.hamburg.de/v1.1/Things?$expand=Locations&$filter=Datastreams/properties/serviceName%20eq%20%27HH_STA_E-Ladestationen%27&$resultFormat=GeoJSON&$top=1000';
getdata(ladestationenUrl, 'Ladestationen', myIcon2, 2);
```

In the code above parametrized function `getdata` takes care of async loading of GeoJSON data from desired source into overlay. It also adds overlay to the layer control. Since loading is async and so order of loading is not known, layer sort is added with the help of layer control `sortFunction` option and overlay custom `order` option (name can be any, as long as it does not conflict with the standard layer options).